# Using VMware for Static IPs and BD Ip Organizer V2.1

Tags: vmware, static-ip

Hardware: Laptop running Windows 8 and A DSL Modem/Wifi from TDS Isp. 6 Static IP addresses from the ISP (5) Useable, (1) Assigned to the the DSL Modem.

What I need to do:

I need to setup Vmware with 5 different virtual environments (Running only one at a time if I have too.) Each of the virtual environment must have one of the static IPs given by the ISP.

Can I individually assign each of the 5 static IPs to each of the 5 virtual environments right in the Vmware software? and or could I use a program like BD Ip Organizer to manually change to the static IP that I need for the specific virtual environment before launching the VMware.

If both are possible what is the easiest way? Also, if it is possible to do it in VMware can I assign the 5 different IPs in VMware and be able to load and use all 5 environments at the same time yet still having a unique IP for each environment.